# Django/Celery can't find importlib

Tags: python, django, celery

So I just updated django to 1.2.3 and now when I try to run 'python manage.py shell' to work in the django environment, I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 18, in handle_noargs
    loaded_models = get_models()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 167, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django_celery-2.0.3-py2.5.egg/djcelery/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from celery import conf
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/celery-2.0.3-py2.5.egg/celery/conf.py", line 6, in <module>
    from celery import routes
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/celery-2.0.3-py2.5.egg/celery/routes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from celery.utils import instantiate, firstmethod, mpromise
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/celery-2.0.3-py2.5.egg/celery/utils/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import importlib
ImportError: No module named importlib
```

Any ideas.  I can't seem to find what's going on here and for all I can tell I'm running the same versions on my web server and I don't have the same error showing up.

Comment: celery should add importlib as a dependency if it's not part of your Python version.  If you didn't install via normal routes, you can install importlib yourself:  easy_install -U importlib

Answer (score 8, accepted):

importlib which was added in Python 2.7/3.1, I believe.  You can download a port for pyton 2.5 here:

- [importlib 1.0.1 - Backport of importlib.import_module() from Python 2.7](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib/1.0.1)

Also check the [`setup.cfg`](http://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/setup.cfg) for celery near the bottom and make sure all the other requirements are met (toward the bottom of the script).

Answer (score 1):

importlib was added to Python in version 3.1, and then backported to Python 2.7. Third party backports are available on PyPI.

Also note that 'backported to 2.7' doesn't imply that all versions after 2.7 will have importlib. Python 3.0, I believe, does *not* have importlib.